# Binary numbers of N digits

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, binary

for generating binary numbers in `n` digit
i did this to get upto 16 binary numbers.

```
n = 6                       # for 6 digits
for i in xrange(16):
    b = bin(i)[2:]
    l = len(b)
    b = str(0) * (n - l) + b
    print b
```

it results like this

```
000000
000001
000010
000011
000100
000101
000110
000111
001000
001001
001010
001011
001100
001101
001110
001111
```

but what i want is to get these values without adding a series of `0s` in prefix.
can anyone help me for this.
  thanks

Comment: Be cautioned that function `xrange()` is specific to Python 2.x; instead, use `range()` for Python 3.x

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove the line that pad `0`s.

```
n = 6
for i in xrange(16):
    b = bin(i)[2:]
    l = len(b)
    #b = str(0) * (n - l) + b  # <--------
    print b
```

---

If you mean padding number without string oeprator, use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) with [`b` type format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
n = 6
for i in xrange(16):
    print '{:0{}b}'.format(i, n)
    # OR  print '{:06b}'.format(i)

    # OR  print '{:b}'.format(i)  if you want no leading 0s.
```

Comment: I think the user meant to format the string with leading zeroes without concating strings

Comment: @kroolik, Thank you for pointing that. I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

If you're asking for a different method:

```
n = 6
for i in xrange(16):
    b = bin(i)[2:].zfill(n)
    print b
```

`str.zfill(n)` pads the string with zeros on the left so that it is at least of length `n`.

---

If you just don't want the leading zeros:

```
for i in xrange(16):
    b = bin(i)[2:]
    print b
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this

Answer (score 3):

You can use list comprehension and bit conversions together like this:
n = range

```
def binary_list(n):
    return ['{:0{}b}'.format(i, n) for i in range(n*n-1)]

print(binary_list(3)) -->
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

or if you want to store each number in its own index do:

```
def binary_list(n):
    return [[int(j) for j in '{:0{}b}'.format(i, n)] for i in range(n*n-1)]

print(binary_list(3))--->
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: the range must be 2**n not n*n-1

Answer (score -1):

By this code you can generate list of binary numbers up to n in O(2^int(log(n))) time complexity.

```
import math

num=25

n=int(math.log(num,2))

x=['0','1']

for i in range(1,int(n)+1):

        for j in range(0,2**i):  

        x.append('1'+x[j])

        x[j]='0'+x[j]



print(x[0:num])
```

output::

```
['00000', '00001', '00010', '00011', '00100', '00101', '00110', '00111', '01000', '01001', '01010', '01011', '01100', '01101', '01110', '01111', '10000', '10001', '10010', '10011', '10100', '10101', '10110', '10111', '11000']
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```
n = 4 
for i in range(0, 2**n):
    b = bin(i)[2:]
    print(str(b).zfill(n))
```

> 0000
> 0001
> 0010
> 0011
> 0100
> 0101
> 0110
> 0111
> 1000
> 1001
> 1010
> 1011
> 1100
> 1101
> 1110
> 1111

n = 6

> 000000
> 000001
> 000010
> 000011 .... 111101
> 111110
> 111111